# GEOSGeometry error creating polygon

Tags: django, geos, django-geoposition

I'm trying to create a polygon from coords but throws the next error:

Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKTReader_read_r".

its not works

```
poly = GEOSGeometry('POLYGON((4.8371311 4.8371311, 4.8371311 4.8371311, 4.6857419 4.6857419, 4.6857419 4.6857419))')
```

but it works

poly = GEOSGeometry('POLYGON((4 4, 4 4, 4 4, 4 4))')

¿Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the problem was that the polygon was incomplete

Comment: It was incomplete because the first and the last coordinate in the polygon needs to be the same.